# Nuget.exe update vs Update-Package in Visual Studio and Web/App.configs

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

When updating a package version for a project via the command line using "nuget update (projectFile|packages.config) -Id (packageName) -NonInteractive" I have a bunch of web.configs generated (with transforms), and the existing app.configs are not transformed.

When updating the same package version for the same project via VS (Update-Package -Id (packageName)), there are no web.configs generated and the appropriate app.configs are transformed.

I realize the web.config's that are created have no adverse effect, but the extra file clutter bothers me.

Why is the behavior inconsistent? And is there a way for the CLI to adhere to the VS behavior (which I want)?

Using the latest version of nuget.exe 4.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the behavior inconsistent?

That because the different behavior of `nuget install` command between NuGet CLI  and Visual Studio.

As we know, config transformations provide a simple way for a package to modify a web.config or app.config **when the package is installed**. And when we update a NuGet package, NuGet will uninstall the old version nuget package, then install the latest nuget package to the project.

However, the behavior of `nuget install` command between NuGet CLI  and Visual Studio are different.

The operation `nuget install` packages on **[NuGet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#commands-and-applicability)**:

[image]

Obviously, NuGet will not re-transform `app.configs` when you using the update-packages operation on the NuGet CLI.

Conversely, operation `nuget-install` packages on [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/powershell-reference):

> Installs a package and its dependencies **into a project**

So using update-package on Visual Studio can appropriately transform app.configs file.

> And is there a way for the CLI to adhere to the VS behavior (which I
>   want)?

To my knowledge, I am afraid the answer is not. Because package manager console is providing is access to visual studio objects. We could not use it with NuGet CLI without Visual Studio:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1512