# Nuget update command result differs from Visual Studio's (Package Manager) update

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have a package (MyPackage) installed in a given project.

If I update it with **Visual Studio (Manage Nuget Packages)** or with **Update-Package** command, such as:

```
Update-Package -Id MyPackage -Version 1.2.8-bla
```

The target project's csproj entry for this package looks like:

```
<Reference Include="MyPackage, Version=1.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\MyPackage.1.2.8-bla\lib\net48\MyPackage.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

But if I update it using **nuget update** command such as:

```
nuget update path_to_csproj -Id MyPackage -Version 1.2.8-bla
```

Then I get:

```
<Reference Include="MyPackage, Version=1.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\MyPackage.1.2.8-bla\lib\net48\MyPackage.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

The `nuget update` command:

- Adds `<Private>True</Private>`
- Adds `PublicKeyToken=null`
- Removes `processorArchitecture=MSIL`

I'd like to understand why and know how I can get the same result I get with Package Manager but using `nuget update` command.

Comment: Are you encountering problems with the two different flavors? Or why is it relevant to you?

Comment: @mu88 So far no problems but I don't know the impact this difference may cause (if any). I'm really curious as of why it's different and if there's a way to keep the consistency.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47627555/17296043) is what you want.